# Android, Not sure if I should store to the internal storage or external storage

Tags: java, android, storage, android-sdcard

I have an app out there on the market already The app is not a game just an informative app with lots of pictures and stats and I received a comment from someone stating that the size of the app being 20Mb is being stored on the "internal storage which isn't fair and that some of it should be stored on the SD card."

Now I am still trying to learn everything about android coding but is this a big deal so that I should move all those images to the external storage like the SD card?  Is 20Mb to the internal storage too much or what number in Mb should I look out for to know when to store to an external?  I looked at the storage documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and it states that the user can modify when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer, so does this pose a risk to my app breaking if the user modifies/removes/changes anything?

Comment: If you were the user of this app, what would you prefer it do?  Which do you usually run out of first, internal or external storage?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah good call to think that way I sometimes forget to think like a user even as a developer.  So basically I should make a check to see if the user has an external storage and if they do save it there and if not continue with it being on the internal storage?

Comment: Is it APK size 20MB or data that the app downloads 20MB?

Comment: @MaciejGórski the APK is 20MB

Comment: @JoeyL That is what I would like my apps to do. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks peter for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install). Just change one thing in the manifest and let users choose where the APK is installed.

> **Note:** By default, your application will be installed on the internal storage and cannot be installed on the external storage unless you define this attribute to be either "auto" or "preferExternal".

Comment: Holy crap this is a great find.  This makes life easier.  This 1 line of code beats all the checking I was thinking about putting.  Thank you Macie.

Comment: @JoeyL The problem was you haven't said that the APK is big. All other answers seem to be answering the case where you use `openFileOutput` instead of external storage.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I am trying to not only learn the coding language but how to phrase my questions when I do have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is no different to a computer having two hard drives, a boot disk and a second disk.

Obvious if you can store using the second disk/external storage, you are generally better off as the internal storage has many uses and usually fills up first.

Generally speaking it is best to leave it to the user to decide but I would store on the external storage by default.

Answer (score 3):

For an older phones it **is** a big deal, believe me. The best option would be to let user choose, which storage he wants to use, in some sort of configuration dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If the app requires those files then do not put them in external storage as that will allow the user to remove them.

If they can be removed/altered then you should put them in external storage.

You could also do a mix of the two so that the size could be reduced without sacrificing the necessary components.