# Make user choose installation destination Android (Internal Storage or SD-Card) from Google Play

Tags: android, storage, google-play, android-sdcard

I have an Android App in Google Play and I want the users to choose whether they want it to be installed in their Internal Storage or in SD-Card.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16861003/2193111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add,

```
android:installLocation="auto"
```

to the manifest inside the  tag

Comment: I have already tried that and I also tried `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` they install it in the Internal Storage then it gives you the choice to move it to the SD-Card.
What I want is to give the user this choice before the installation starts.

Comment: OK @r2DoesInc thanks! Is there a way to force the installation to go to the SD-Card?